# Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app for iOS without Mac?

Tags: ios, html, cordova

So I have a HTML 5 app and I have access to Apple Developer Center (iOS Dev Center to be more exact). The question is can I actually use it without buying (lending) Mac? Meaning, can I create/download my developer certificate and a provisioning profile from Windows or Linux?

Comment: did you successfully achieve to create the app for ios?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to this article, you no longer need a Mac?

https://web.archive.org/web/20150303180446/http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

Edit: Link updated

Comment: this is not about building apps, you still need a machine with ios installed, this is just about certificate generation

Comment: Actually you don't need one if you use PhoneGap Build. You only need to generate a certificate and add link to your github project. It's free for open source apps. Closed source apps are supported on PhoneGap Build but you have to pay some fee for it - still probably cheaper then Mac ;-).

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but i can tell that you may hit some issues with PhoneGap build, I remember that PayPal plugin wasn't supported for example. So will I be able to build using cordova build on Windows?

Comment: Could you please update your answer or remove it? The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 25):

For those wondering how to sign their app for iOS in Windows, here's how you can do so: [building an iOS signing key for PhoneGap in Windows](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows).

You still need an Apple Developer Account, there's no getting around that.

Comment: That was an awesomely simple article!  Thanks.  Part of the tricky thing is that on the Apple Developer pages, it says "upload this from XCode or **your Mac**"  implying (falsely) that you can only upload from a Mac.

Comment: will i need apple developer account..if i jailbreak my phone

Comment: Your phone has nothing to do with having an Apple Developer account, so yes you will still need one to carry out this task.

Comment: @Ian Devlin I have built an app in windows too and then packaged it up using phonegap build. Is it possible to test the app on ios before submitting it? Ie download it to my iphone? do i need to sign it first? thanks

Answer (score 9):

No it's not possible.
You can **build** your phonegap application in the cloud without a Mac (with some limitations depending on the [build plan you choose](https://build.phonegap.com/)).

As @stu sais, you may be able to make a certificate for Apple Store using Windows.
But, finally, you will need a Mac with Xcode installed to updload your application to the App Store.

Comment: I won't vote down, but that is not true. You can generate all needed certificates on Windows (see previous answers). You can also sign the application by sending your key to PhoneGap Build. From PGB you get valid ipa file which should be enough to push your app to the Apple Store.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, you can get ipa file in windows thats right, but - to upload the ipa to itunes connect you must have mac! no other way, so to be the app store you must have mac

Comment: There's a few sketchy third party sites that will take your login and password and submit your .ipa for you.  You can also get an illegal copy of OSx and run it in a virtual machine.  Meanwhile, Google lets you just upload the signed APK via a webform.  WHAT IS WRONG WITH YOU APPLE??

Comment: one more point could be if you got any error like icons missing or some other type of error then how will you debug that error. debugging is possible in mac only. Sometimes app works fine in android but someproblem occur in ios

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible, via PhoneGap Build. https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: And how do I sign my app without Mac, then?

Comment: Gee, that sounds like a Frequently Asked Question. https://build.phonegap.com/faq "For Android, iOS, and BlackBerry, you'll need to provide the correct certificates and/or signing keys to allow distribution."

Comment: Well, can you find the word "Windows" there ;-P

Comment: Not a very thorough answer, is that...? ;-)

Comment: @Alastair The question is "Is it possible?" The answer is "Yes." I even threw in a link to one place you can easily do so.

Comment: @ceejayoz that service allows you to compile packages using your own certificates from the iOS dev. programme but suggesting [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), alone, is not a complete solution (without mentioning the certificate issues).

Comment: @Alastair The iOS dev program website can be accessed on a Windows machine to get the certificates. I'm not sure what clarification you're trying to recommend.

Comment: How should be the structure to generate in https://build.phonegap.com?, I mean, I uploades a folder www with my source code, and it doesn't work, the site generate .ipa and install it in my iPod, just appear splash by default.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually you need a Mac to submit your iOS apps. You can simply try the Remote Mac Server [MacinCloud](http://www.MacinCloud.com) with your PC. You can install PhoneGap and develop iOS in the Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cert for apple store using windows. Anyone who says otherwise has no idea. I'm doing it my self. Just install ssl into windows and run it from cmd prompt. Find a tutorial on how to create a certificate for mac store using ssl from cmd.

Comment: Where can I "find a tutorial on how to create a certificate"?