# Is developing an iOS app using PhoneGap on Windows 7 possible?

Tags: ios, windows, cordova

I am going to be developing an iOS app to run on an iPad and I'm going to do it using PhoneGap.  Is it possible to develop it on a Windows 7?  I've been reading through the PhoneGap documentation and it doesn't say its not possible but I thought I'd ask here to avoid starting and getting stuck.  Can anyone speak from experience to say is possible?  Also my app doesn't need to be published on the App Store if that makes a difference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app for iOS without Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is basically off-topic for SO, but I'll answer it anyway because it has a quick answer.

You can develop your PhoneGap app on any platform, but in order to build it for iPhone you need a Mac with the appropriate Xcode-based toolchain. Or you can use the Adobe PhoneGap Build service: https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: If Apple provides option to built it on windows it would be great. since it seems platform dependent for developing App for Apple smart devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using virtual machine:
[link](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc-on-virtualbox/)

Comment: Well, requirement says: _Mac OS X. Tested on 10.11 El Capitan, 10.12 Sierra, iOS 9.0 and iOS 10.0_ It don't even answer the question.