# Develope/ debug phonegap for ios on windows

Tags: ios, cordova

I have windows machine. Is it possible to build/ debug phonegap for ios on windows? . I have seen a few answers but I am not sure what is the current status.
Pay attention I refer specifically to developing with phonegap! not to general ios development!

Answer (score 0):

[Is developing an iOS app using PhoneGap on Windows 7 possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537065/is-developing-an-ios-app-using-phonegap-on-windows-7-possible)

This has been asked before.

The answer is there for you to read yourself, but essentially you need to have access to a Mac with the appropriate xcode based tool chain in some shape or form.

Comment: a few articales say it is possible on windows is this true/ still true    http://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/ http://www.tipsfromsiliconvalley.com/2013/09/18/developp-and-build-an-ios-apple-application-on-windows-with-phonegap/

Comment: Yes, as long as those third party websites work. That's also mentioned in the original question linked. The website builds it for you on a Mac effectively. Or the other one, you're sacrificing some of the functionality of phonegap by using the parts that don't require the xcode based tool chain, I would imagine. I've never done either myself, so I'm not 100% on the mechanics. But if you don't care about the specifics: Yes. Those work. It's more of a hassle, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks. So basically I need to create a certificate, and then use phonegap build service. A bit of a shame I won't be able to debug though.