# Is it possible to make a cordova CLI app for iOS without Mac?

Tags: ios, windows, cordova

I read in the post [Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app for iOS without Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac) that it is possible to create a phonegap app for ios without a mac.

Therefore it should also be possible to do the same with a cordova app.

I am a bit confused because in the official documentation  [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support) it is written that such an app can just be created on a mac.

Is it possible to make a cordova CLI app for iOS without Mac on a windows machine?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to publish app to applestore without mac.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build an IOS App as per this [App without MAC](http://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/) article without using a MAC. There is another article on phoneGap website link [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac) 
Check it out.

Comment: is it also the same with cordova ?

Comment: Yes. Why not? Basically cordova and PhoneGap are similar. Infact PhoneGap uses cordova internally.