# Developing cross platform app

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I have developed a phonegap app (android) using Eclipse IDE. Is there any way by which I can use same HTML, CSS and Js to develop IOS app? I do not have a Mac system to do that. Do I need Mac System or can it be done on windows? Do I need to have developer account? Can It be done without having Developer account? How can I create .ipa file without using Mac system?

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: windows 7, 32 bin Operating system

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac.  That any use?

Comment: You must have a Developer account to build IOS app, without Mac OSX system. You can use Phonegap Build to build app automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your code on this it will generate IPA for you

https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: But this needs a developer account and provisioning profile right?

Comment: Yes.provisioning profile and developer account is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
Do I need Mac System or can it be done on windows?
```

Yes, you will need a Mac computer in order to compile it for iOS. You might want to use Xcode for the compilation purpose or test/deploy the application on device. You also need a Mac to configure certificates and provising profiles. Moreover, iOS Simulator does not run on Windows. Hence, Mac is a must one even if you develop app using web technologies.

```
Do I need to have developer account?  Can It be done without having Developer account?
```

You won't need to have a developer account for writing applications for iOS. However, you will certainly need to have one when you want to test the app on your device. You will not be able to test your application on a device unless you have a developer account.

```
How can I create .ipa file without using Mac system?
```

Without a Mac system, this will not be possible. But, you might want to see more info on PhoneGap Build from this  [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_build_without_mac).

Answer (score 1):

I just find the following in which he can explain **setting up building iOS apps without a Mac**

**1)**http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

**2)**http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows

Comment: No it can't.You must have Apples developer certificate for this.