# Can I use PhoneGap Build to create iOS apps with a Windows computer?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-cli

I want to know if Mac is compulsory to use for building iOS app in PhoneGap Build?
I have surfed many sites from which some says it is mandatory while some says it's not.
I want to create iOS app using PhoneGap Build but without using Mac and also without using virtual machine. There should not be any future errors in the alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac

Comment: @R9J: Actually, this doesn't seem to be duplicate of that. As you can see, this is about PhoneGap Build (which is cloud build service for Cordova projects) and that question is about possibility to build Cordova (formerly PhoneGap) project for iOS without Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing some concepts. PhoneGap Build is cloud service to build Cordova projects without the need to install the SDKs and IDEs necessary when built with Cordova CLI. To use it, you do not need absolutely anything else than account there and git repository for your project. You can use Windows, Linux or even OS X to develop your app and with any IDE you wish, even Notepad if you wish so. PhoneGap Build will then fetch your project from the git repository and build it with their own servers which have the required SDKs etc. to make it possible. That is the great part of it!

Comment: You don't even need a git repository. Uploading a zipped project folder is possible, too.