# No need Macbook for Phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am just involve in Phonegap development project and i am not sure to spend money on Macbook or not. Plus, i was never touch Mac before.

I just read related topic to my question [Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app for iOS without Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac) but this topic was discussed 4 years ago and i wonder if its still work? and i do read [Phonegap Faq](https://build.phonegap.com/faq) that through Build Phonegap, we are able to generate ios app by using signed key and able to submit to App Store.

If possible, thats mean we just only need to pay a fee to Phonegap and save cost from buying Macbook right ?

Comment: Please, instead of asking the same thing, add a comment in the original question/answers.

Comment: on 4 years ago topic?

Comment: This isn't a forum, this is a QA website: if you are searching now for a problem you want to resolve it now. Old question should be updated if new  or better solution are found. There is also a [specific badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) for good new answers to old questions :)

Comment: You don't need a mac for creating the app, but you need it to submit it to the apple store

Comment: @jcesarmobile i thought Enterprise Phonegap Build have features for submitting app to App Store without using a Mac?

Comment: as far as I know, they just give you the app signed and you have to upload it using "application loader" app

Answer (score 0):

No, you must create certificate for your app from mac-OS only. And that certificate file and key you will upload to Phonegap build at compilation time, and then you can publish it to iTunes and that is also from Mac-OS only.
There is no means to generate iOS signing through Phonegap build.

Comment: Can u confirm about this? [iOS Signing in Phonegap](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html#_windows_users)

Comment: [Application signing](https://build.phonegap.com/faq)  have a look at question no-5 on this page.. I am sure and I already published my app name is 'Phalcomm' on windows, android and iTunes

Comment: Why my answer is down voted..? I provided the correct answer as per Phonegap standards are concerned

Comment: Your answer may not right while i found this. [Detailed Guide for setting up building iOS apps without a Mac](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac) but that guide was 4 years ago.

Comment: Ok..then go with that link..but I am not comfortable with solutions given before 4 yrs.. try your luck...but i can assure u that it will not work

Answer (score -1):

PhoneGap project is written in Java Script. So you don't need to touch macbook.
either you can start your project by Xcode(with macbook) or You can start you project by eclipse(windows). When you want to take a build it will prompt you options to select for .ipa(ios), .apk(android),windows-phone,black-berry, Symbrian.

Note: only for ios you need to provide some info to make ipa (i,e keychain etc)
**But a very careful thing is that you should first check from phonegap website that your all requirement can be developed by phonegap. There may have a possibility that some of your features may not support to develop by phonegap**

Comment: have you ever worked with phonegap or cordova or have you just used google to find out what does happen if you run `cordova build`? Of course you will need a mac for generating the certificates. There is no way to do this on a windows machine.

Comment: @Sithys if u refer the topic and link i mention above, some ppls said its possible to generate certificates in windows.

Comment: In this question regarding "If possible, thats mean we just only need to pay a fee to Phonegap and save cost from buying Macbook right ?" Only for keychain you need to buy a macbook? you can share you keychain to other

Comment: > some ppls said...

Yes, some said but it is not possible.

Comment: you did not consider that one can run his ios app in windows machine

Comment: did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac